# Dracena Marginata has new leaves growing white

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations

I've had this dracena plant for almost 2 years now and today I noticed that the top growing leaves are white. Is this normal? I looked at the top leaves a while ago and didn't notice the white colours.

[image: Dracena Marginata with white leaves]

[image: New leaves growing white]

Comment: Did it experience any temperature/sun conditions change recently? Looks like some sun damage, as it has been in shade for long time and then put to direct light

Comment: I've moved it from the window on top of a flower rack that's more on the shadier side. My window is facing east so I get a few hours of direct sunlight per day. I've had it on the window shelf for a year and it didn't get any white leaves like those in the picture. I think that's how new leaves look since the other older leaves look healthy.